# java regex to replace few groups in input with particular string

Tags: java, regex, replace

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class Regex {

        public static void main(String args[]){     

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(cat).*?(dog)?.*?(tiger)");
            String input = "The cat is a tiger";
            Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
            if (m.find()) {

            //In the output i want to replace input string with group 3 with group 1 value and group 2 with cow. Though group2 is present or not.
//i.e. group 2 is null
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd like to know whether it is possible in java to use regex to replace an input string with a particular value for captured groups.

Please help

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your requirements.  Can you give us a couple of examples to illustrate?  For example, what do you expect the output to be when the input is "The cat is a tiger"?  And what do you expect the output to be when the input is "My dog ate a tiger"?

Comment: Please elaborate your requirements, if you know what has to be replaced and with what value, you can use `String.replace(target, replacement)`

Comment: i want output like this. "The cat is a cow tiger". (Though the sentence is meaningless. i'm here explaining context. ) Also if input is "The cat is a dog and a tiger. Then output will be " The cat is a cow and a cat"

Comment: so did anything help?

Answer (score 0):

The String class's `replace` and `replaceAll` methods are the best way to do this. They support regex strings as the search argument.

Comment: `replace()` actually replaces each EXACT match of the given string or char. `replaceFirst()` and `replaceAll()` can be used with regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(cat)(.*?)(dog)?(.*?)(tiger)");
String input = "The cat is a tiger";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find())
{
  m.appendReplacement(str, "$5$2$3$4$1");
}
m.appendTail(str);
System.out.println(str);
```

By the way if it doesn’t matter whether there’s a dog you can simplify it:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(cat)(.*?)(tiger)");
String input = "The cat is a tiger";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find())
{
  m.appendReplacement(str, "$3$2$1");
}
m.appendTail(str);
```

Comment: Just as a side note: That’s the equivalent to `String result="The cat is a tiger".replaceAll("(cat)(.*?)(dog)?(.*?)(tiger)", "$5$2$3$4$1");` so if you want to do it just once that single line will do too.